# Understanding why exec($my_command) hang

Tags: php, exec

I have an exec() call wich never end, and my Apache/PHP process is blocked until timeout.
It's an PostgreSQL database load like that

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\bin"\psql --host 127.0.0.1 --dbname unitTests --file C:\ZendStd\www\voo4\trunk\resources\sql\base_test_projectx.pg.sql --username postgres 2>&1
```

It run fine in command line, but just block when called via php exec() function.
I just want to understand why my exec() call never end, I think psql ask for a password but how I can print the output before the call end?

I use PHP 5.2.12 on Windows XP, with PGSql 8.3.

Comment: It sounds like environmental problems to me.  Can you tell if it is running at all?  Does it actually start and never end, or does it perhaps never even start?  Can you look in the database to see if you made a connection?

Comment: There is no connection, but the command begin to execute. With another command I have the output, I just want to analyse the problem of this command.

Answer (score 2):

You could use passthru() which directly outputs everything. Or you use some process control functions.